# getEngine().getState() == Engine.IDLE represents what in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

```
getEngine().getState() == Engine.IDLE
```

I found this inside slider when enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slider is only enabled (clickable) when the model is not running and not finished (i.e. in an "idle" state).

You can always read up on things like this in the help. Engine states are explained [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/running/engine-api.html#engine-api), for example:
[image]